# Change on DataTables rows returned

Tags: jquery, datatables

There is an option for displaying a search box to filter by. What if I would like to have a predefined select box to choose entries from for a particular field?

For instance, if I add a select element that has a list of categories that narrow the displayed rows by `category_id`. What part of the API would I used to tell DataTables to refresh the AJAX results based on the change in that value?

Obviously, I'd use `ajax.reload()` method, but how do I filter by that `category_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option to add additional parameter to be sent to the server and that would be your filter value.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/test/0",
        "data": function(d){            
            d.form_filter = $('#example-select').val();
        }
    }
});

// Handle filter change event
$('#example-select').on('change', function(){
    // Reload table data from Ajax data source
    $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(); 
});
```

You need to handle this parameter (`form_filter` in my example) on the server and return corresponding data.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3w18bygt/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Getting error `$.mockjax is not a function` when I try to run the fiddle.

Comment: @eComEvo, updated link to mockjax library just in case, but it works for me. Please note, that I use it for demonstration only, it's not needed for production.

Comment: Now it works for me as well! Thanks for cluing me in to `mockjax`, BTW. Cool tool.